# Why do grub.cfg and actual boot options differ?

Tags: grub2

After a recent upgrade my boot options were changed.

Following instructions I found, I downloaded a tool called `grub-cfg` and used it to change my boot options.  Unfortunately, it didn't work.

The options from my configuration in `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` and the boot options that are actually shown are different.  Here are my grub.cfg headers (my full grub.cfg is [here](http://sonic.net/~sjs/grub.cfg)):

```
menuentry "Ubuntu" --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class ...
menuentry "Ubuntu, with Linux 12.04 3.2.0-24-generic" --class ubuntu ...
menuentry "Memory test (memtest86+)"
menuentry "Memory test (memtest86+, serial console 115200)" 
menuentry "Windows 7 (loader) (on /dev/sda1)" --class windows ...
menuentry "Windows Recovery Environment (loader) (on /dev/sda3)" --...
```

The boot menu actually looks like:

[image: Options shown are different from the menuentries in grub.cfg!]

If I understand things right, the entries from the grep are exactly what I should be seeing on the boot screen, but they obviously aren't.  I want the grub boot options to be what I set them to with grub config; the default should take me to the 12.10 kernel instead of the 12.04 (2.6.38-16 generic) kernel.  What's going on?

Here is a bit more information.  I was looking at /var/log/system.1 and found the following

> Dec 26 14:23:20 hikari 40grub2: Skipping entry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.2.0-23-generic (on /dev/sdb6)':
>   Dec 26 14:23:20 hikari 40grub2: appears to be an automatic reference taken from another menu.lst
>   ...
>   Dec 26 14:23:20 hikari 40grub2: debug: parsing: ### END /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###

What's particularly interesting here is that on my system I have windows 7, Ubuntu 12.04 and Ubuntu 12.10.  The grub.d/41_custom file lives on the 12.04 system not the 12.10.

So what happened is that after the last upgrade grub is reading 12.10 /boot/grub.cfg but parsing the /etc/grub.d from the 12.04 area.

Does anyone have suggestions where to look next?

How can this be?

Answer (score 1):

After considering the discovery that reboot used a different partion for the /etc/grub.d files than the current OS version, I decided it must be using grub from the older install.  I looked at the grub configuration graphical tool and discovered an option to re-install the MBR and did this.  Problem solved -- I now boot from the proper grub.cfg file.

Thanks for the assistance.  The suggestion about grub.d by WindowsEscapest is what put me on the right track.
Steve S.